# Shortcut for duplicating and decreasing stroke width incrementally illustrator CS6

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6, transform

I use transform again to duplicate paths/shapes at an equal distance. I was wondering if there was a way do make a stroke on a path incrementally smaller? So I could just hit command d or any other alternative that would work so I could define an even amount of increments it would go down by.

[image]

Comment: Use a blend you can then even adjust number of steps after the fact.

Comment: @joojaa Ah yes I forgot the blend tool could do that I was just thinking colour gradiation

Comment: You can self answer and ill upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Use a **Blend**...

- Draw two strokes, one the thickest you want, and one the thinnest.
- Select both
- Choose `Object > Blend > Make` from the menu
- You can then adjust the Blend by choosing `Object > Blend > Blend Options`

[image]

If you then want access to each step of the blend, choose `Object > Expand` from the menu and you'll have a collection of stroked paths.

[image]